# logical expression as result

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

What is happening here?

```
true && false || true  //true
false && false || true //true
false && true || false //false
true && true || false  //true

1 && 2 || 3  //2

3 && 2 || 1  //2

2 && 5 || 3  //5
```

more cases

```
5 && 7 || 10 
7
5 && 7 || 1 
7
9 && 7 || 1 
7
9 && 0 || 1 
1
0 && 7 || 1 
1
9 && 7 || 0 
7
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: You don't want us to do your homework, do you?

Comment: Thanks, I always read this and forgot. any way to remember for always.

Comment: @Psi lol, I have around 10 years experience and every time I face this sentence and I hove to google it or have to search it. any way to remember it for always

Comment: Use the acronym "Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally", which stands for Parentheses-Exponentation-Multiplication-Division-Addition-Subtraction. Then remember that `&&` is a kind of multiplication, and `||` is a kind of addition, in logical terms. Hence, `&&` has higher precedence (binds more tightly) than `||`.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript:

```
 A && B || C
```

means:

```
 if (A){
   B // it calls B
 }
 else{
   C
 }
```

Therefore,

true(A) && false(B) || true(C) means

```
if (true) // This is A
{
   // The code goes here because A is true
   false; // This is B
}
else
{
   true; // This is C
}
```

Let me give you an example:

```
1 && 2 || 3
```

means:

```
if (1) {
   2;
}
else {
   3;
}
```

In javascript all numbers but "0" is equivalent to "true" and "0" is equivalent to "false".

Comment: I don't think this is how it interpreted. see my examples. it's not satisfying them.

Comment: I don't understand how it satisfy the condition.

Comment: In javascript all numbers but "0" is equivalent to "true" and "0" is equivalent to "false"

Comment: In javascript if (true) === if (1) //// if (false) === if (0)

Comment: @AHBagheri wnat about this one --> false && false || true //true